# Using value of an attribute of django object in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a model named VisitorInfo in models.py which is as follows:

```
class VisitorInfo(models.Model):
    #To maintain clarity i am not showing all the fields.

    visitor_id      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    pages_visited   = models.ManyToManyField(Page,blank=True)
    time_zone       = models.CharField(max_length=120, null= True, blank=True)
    ip              = models.CharField(max_length=120, null= True, blank=True)
    device_type     = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
```

Following is the view where i am using this model.

```
class Live_Now(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/live_now.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Live_Now, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    search = self.request.GET.get('q')

    if search:
        if VisitorInfo.objects.filter(Q_filter).filter(active=True).count() >0:
            context['list_no'] = VisitorInfo.objects.filter(Q_filter).filter(active=True)
        else:
            context['list_no'] = "N"
    return context
```

What i need to do as soon as live_now.html page loads and Live_Now view runs, a new tab will open with following url.

```
url = 54.161.109.227:5000/visitor_id
```

I know that to open a new tab i have to write down script in live_now.html which is as follows.

```
<script type='text/javascript>
window.open(url); // Above written url
</script>
```

But how do i fetch visitor_id of the visitor at runtime. Fetching visitor_id is the task fo python function and opening new tab is the function of javascript. How do i pass value of python variable in javascript program ?

For time being i am fetching visitor_id of first visitor in visitors and i have written the following function to do this.

```
def myfunc():
    visitors= VisitorInfo.objects.all()
    for visitor in visitors[:1]:
        visitorId = visitor.visitor_id
        return str(visitorId)
```

Comment: on document.load function call an ajax which will call the above written function to return the visitor id and the call the window.open function to call the url

Comment: PS: Most of the modern browsers prevent opening a new window/popup and gives the user the freedom to decide. You might need to use a CSS based light-box like model windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this much harder than it needs to be. If you need your JS to have a particular value, then pass it there.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ... existing code ...
    context['visitor_id'] = Visitor.objects.first().user_id
    return context
```

...

```
url = "54.161.109.227:5000/{{ visitor_id }}";
window.open(url)
```

Of course you can just as easily pass the whole Visitor object to the template and do `{{ visitor.user_id }}`, it's up to you.

Comment: Sir @danielroseman, what if i want to pass this visitor_id in a separate javascript file? How can i achieve that ?